# ticactoe AI playing very badly! - likely error in minimax algorithm (cs50 AI)

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, cs50, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I'm currently doing a cs50 intro to AI course whereby I need to complete several functions for a tic-tac-toe game to run. When playing it, however, the AI plays badly, normally picking squares at the top left which I'm pretty sure is to do with my minimax function. With some debugging it showed that the variables `foo` and `bar` (there to try to get the highest value of `min-value(result(s, a))` for maximising player and for minimising opponent) do not change and stay at their original -infinity and infinity. I don't understand however why this happens. below is the code and any help would be great!

```
def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    #Checking if game is over
    if terminal(board):
        return None
    else:
        #Check whose turn it is
        turn = player(board)
        board_actions = actions(board)
        if turn == 'X':
            action_score_max = -math.inf
            return_value_min = board_actions[0]
            #return_value_max 
            for a in board_actions:
                foo = min_value(result(board, a))
                if foo > action_score_max:
                    action_score_max = foo
                    return_value_max = a
            
            return return_value_max

        else:
            action_score_min = math.inf
            return_value_min = board_actions[0]
            for a in board_actions:
                bar = max_value(result(board, a))
                if bar < action_score_min:
                    action_score_min = bar
                    return_value_min = a
            
            return return_value_min




def max_value(board):

    """
    Helper function for minimax (pick max value value of all routes)
    """

    v = -math.inf

    for action in actions(board):
        v = max(v, min_value(result(board, action)))
    
    return v



def min_value(board):

    """
    Helper function for minimax (pick min value value of all routes)
    """

    v = math.inf

    for action in actions(board):
        v = min(v, max_value(result(board, action)))

    return v
```

Answer (score 0):

As the description of your minimax function suggests, Its job is to return the optimal move for the current player, and to do that you've 2 helper functions `max_value` and `min_value`, those are the ones where you should implement your logic so that it gets and returns the optimal move.

You could do something like that-

```
def minimax(board):
    """
    Returns the optimal action for the current player on the board.
    """
    if terminal(board):
        return None
        
    if player(board) == O:
        move = min_value(board)[1]
    else:
        move = max_value(board)[1]
    return move

def max_value(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return [utility(board), None]
    v = float('-inf')
    best_move = None
    for action in actions(board):
        hypothetical_value = min_value(result(board, action))[0]
        if hypothetical_value > v:
            v = hypothetical_value
            best_move = action
    return [v, best_move]


def min_value(board):
    if terminal(board):
        return [utility(board), None]
    v = float('inf')
    best_move = None
    for action in actions(board):
        hypothetical_value = max_value(result(board, action))[0]
        if hypothetical_value < v:
            v = hypothetical_value
            best_move = action
    return [v, best_move]
```